# Как лучше из объекта получить массив его keys , у которых свойство = true?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как заменить на более es6, чтобы обойтись без let и push

```
const obj1 = {
    'prop-1': {
      name: 'test',
      selected: false,
    },
    'prop-2': {
      name: 'ted4',
      selected: true,
    },
    'prop-3': {
      name: 'е',
      selected: false,
    },
    'prop-4': {
      name: 'tet2222',
      selected: true,
    },
  }


  let result = []
  for(const key in obj1) {
    var value = obj1[key];
    if (value.selected) {
      result.push(key)
    }
}
```

Из объекта obj1 получить массив keys, у которых свойство selected = true

В данном случае на выходе получаем

```
["prop-2", "prop-4"]
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Получаем все имена свойств объекта с помощью [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
2. Фильтруем полученный массив с помощью [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) с колбеком: `key =>
   obj1[key].selected`.

```js
const obj1 = {
    'prop-1': {
      name: 'test',
      selected: false,
    },
    'prop-2': {
      name: 'ted4',
      selected: true,
    },
    'prop-3': {
      name: 'е',
      selected: false,
    },
    'prop-4': {
      name: 'tet2222',
      selected: true,
    },
  }

const result = Object.keys(obj1).filter(key => obj1[key].selected);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Object.entries` возвращает массив массивов вида

```
[
  [ 'prop-1', { name: 'test', selected: false } ],
  [ 'prop-2', { name: 'ted4', selected: true } ],
  ...
]
```

Вычисляем результат с помощью reduce.

```
const result = Object.entries(obj1)
  .reduce(
    // Конструкция [key, value] представляет
    // собой деструктуризацию массива [ 'prop-1', { name: 'test', selected: false } ],
    // когда мы в key записываем 'prop-1', а в value записываем { name: 'test', selected: false }.
    (keys, [key, value]) => (value.selected ? [...keys, key] : keys),
    [], // Начальное значение для ключей.
  );
```

Comment: `Object.entries(obj1).filter(([k, { selected }]) => selected).map(([k]) => k)` можно еще так мозг взрорвать)